# Move each character of a div based on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a site and I don't know how to create a javascript animation that looks like this:

I have a `div` that have some text on it, and when the user moves his mouse *over* this text, I want each character to move independently of each other, in order to maintain a certain distance from it (the mouse). Also, I want this animation to have rotation, but it isn't that important now. Here's an image explanation:

[image: explanation]

**Here's what I did so far:**

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">Hello World</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var chars = $(".div1").html().split('');
$(".div1").empty();
for(var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    $(".div1").append("<span class='letter'>"+chars[i]+"</span>");
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/6fk8H/1/)

---

Can someone help me to achieve this effect? I don't know how to proceed and there's no site or answer that helped me. You *can* use jQuery or pure JavaScript but, please, **keep it simple!** Thank you.

Comment: Calculate the angle and distance, and apply them on the characters \* *geometry* \*

Comment: But how can I apply the angle and distance for each character independently of each other, if all the characters have the same class?

Comment: Apply different CSS values for each of them

Comment: I tried this to change the CSS of each character independently using jquery, but it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/6fk8H/3/

Comment: http://jschr.github.io/textillate/ You should be using some olug-in like this http://jschr.github.io/textillate/ if your purpose is not learning

Comment: @TiagoMarinho - I don't think that's the way to do it, but that depends on what you're trying to do? Maybe start with something closer to this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6fk8H/4/

Comment: @TiagoMarinho - One main (big) issue in your code is that you are registering one extra event listener every 500ms.

Comment: @adeneo your fiddle is almost what I'm trying to do. The `x` and `y` vars are storing the user mouse position?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 how I can solve this issue? If I remove the setInterval the color still not change.

Comment: @Foreever **I want to learn!**

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but if it where me the next step would be to figure out the direction the mouse pointer is moving (it's not that hard, add a little tolerance as well), then figure out where the character is in relation to the mouse pointer, so that if the character is on the left side of the mousepointer, move left, but also dependent on if the mouse is travelling just left, or maybe move the character up and left if the mouse pointer is moving that way etc. Then I would try and figure out the mouse movement speed, and move the character based on that.

Comment: And suddenly you realize it's more complicated than you think, but it is doable. Maybe look at collision algorithms for games etc ?

Comment: Yeah it looks complicated and I was thinking about doing this using `canvas` but I think it can be made without it.

Comment: I think that, to get the mouse movement direction we can check if the mouse distance is greater or less than zero, (and not using Math.abs on `distX` and `distY` to do this). Here's what I tried, but it looks strange: http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/6fk8H/5/.

Comment: Maybe look into [d3js](http://www.d3js.org) and its force layouts?

Comment: @Luxelin thank you but I prefer using a jQuery-only solution.

Comment: Okay I'm almost making it, can someone help me to finish? Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/6fk8H/9/ but the characters don't go up if `y > $(".letter" + i).offset().top`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh here we go, I've found a solution for this.

What I did was using a different class name for each character (`.letter` + character number) and then created a way of moving the characters depending on the mouse position and distance compared to each character, so, for example, when the distance between the mouse and a character is less than X, and the mouse `Y` is less than the character `Y`, then the character will go down.

Thanks to [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) and [Derek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283863/derek)

**Here's the relevant code:**

JavaScript:

```
var chars = $(".div1").html().split('');
$(".div1").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    $(".div1").append("<span class='letter" + i + "'>" + chars[i] + "</span>");
    $(".letter" + i).css({
        "position":"relative",
    });
    $(".letter" + i).css({
        "transition": "0.5s"
    });
}

$(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        var x = e.pageX,
            y = e.pageY;
        var distx = x - $(".letter" + i).offset().left + ($(".letter" + i).width() / 2);
        var disty = y - $(".letter" + i).offset().top;

    if (Math.abs(distx) < 24 && Math.abs(disty) < 24) {
        if (distx > 6 || distx < -6) {
            if (x < $(".letter" + i).offset().left) {
                $(".letter" + i).css({
                    "left": + (24 / Math.abs(distx) * Math.abs(distx)),
                        "position": "relative"
                });
            } else {
                $(".letter" + i).css({
                    "left": - (24 / Math.abs(distx) * Math.abs(distx)),
                        "position": "relative"
                });
            }
        }

        if (disty > 12 || disty < -12) {
            if (y < $(".letter" + i).offset().top + 6) {
                $(".letter" + i).css({
                    "top": + (24 / Math.abs(disty) * Math.abs(disty)),
                        "position": "relative"
                });
            } else {
                $(".letter" + i).css({
                    "top":  - (24 / Math.abs(disty) * Math.abs(disty)),
                        "position": "relative"
                });
            }
        }
    }
    distx = 0;
    disty = 0;
}
```

});

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">Hello World</div>
```

[**Updated JSFiddle with CSS Transitions to improve smoothness**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/6fk8H/18/)

Comment: Oh nice, you find a way to do it ;), maybe you could make it into a js "class" so its better organized for further usage =)

Answer (score 1):

Well since you say yo want to learn, i'll give a code to help you out, but you have to work your way through, i haven't test it, i just wrote it blindly so it propably won't work but might give you a good idea of what must be done.

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="coolDiv" class="scatterContainer">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
*{margin:0;}
span:hover{
    color:#0CF;
}
.scatterContainer{
    display: inline;
}
.container {
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

Javascript

```
LetterScatterer = (function() {

  function LetterScatterer(id) {

    this.id = id
    this.$el = $('#' + this.id);
    this.rangeOfaction = 3; // Number of characters to affect
    this.maxVerticalMovement = 10; // Value in px
    this.minVerticalMovement = 2
    this.duration = 100; // In miliseconds



    // Event Listeners

    this.$el.on(mousemove((function(_this){

        return function(e){

            var x = e.pageX;
            var y = e.pageY;

            return _this.scatter(x, y);
        }

    })(this));

  }

  LetterScatterer.prototype.splitCharacters = function() {
    var nodes = [];
    var nodesQ = 0;
    var _this = this;
    this.chars = $el.text().split('');
    $el.empty();


    for(var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        var markup = "<span class='letter'>"+chars[i]+"</span>";
        nodes.push(markup);
    }

    this.$nodes = $(nodes);

    this.nodesWidth = [];
    this.$nodes.each(function(){
        var width = $(this).outerWidth();
        _this.nodesWidth.push(width);
    });

    $el.append(this.$nodes);


  }

  LetterScatterer.prototype.scatter = function(x, y) {
    var epicenter;
    var offset = 0;
    var midPoint, farestLeft;

    for(var i = 0, len = this.nodesWidth.length; i < len; i++){
        offset += this.nodesWidth[i];
        if(x <= offset){
            epicenter = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    leftRange = (this.rangeOfaction - 1) / 2; // We remove one, this is our epicenter, then we get left and right halves


    farestLeft = epicenter - leftRange;
    for(var i = farestLeft; i < this.rangeOfaction; i++){
        this.animateY($node[i]);
    }


  }


  LetterScatterer.prototype.animateY = function(node, verticalDisplacement) {
    var $node = $(node);
    $node.animate({margin-top: verticalDisplacement + 'px'}, this.duration);
  }



  return LetterScatterer;

})();

letterScatterer = new LetterScatterer('coolDiv');
```

What you see in the code is a classlike function, first you pass it the id of the element containing the text that will be scattered. There are some config varaibles, range of action is lets say, if you mouse over one character, how many characters to the left and to the right (also including the current hovered element) should be animated, the max and min verticalMovement, determines how much should move the one that is hovered (max) and those further apart will use min, those in between should interpolate, but i didn't code that far.

We then got a mousemove listener, that calls the method scatter, this method finds which items is currently hovered by adding up each character widht, but now i think about it, it should be easier to just add a listener to the span, and get the current index of that element with the jQuery method index(), then based on that index you animate that one and those in the range. You must create the code that calculates the rotation, and x movement if you want to, but i think i gave you a lot to start, it took me a while to code it, so i hope it helps and this answer satisfies your question. :)

Comment: thank you a lot for your help, but since your code needs more HTML markup, more JavaScript lines and wasn't tested, I think my solution is better (I already answered my solution here, as you can see if you scroll down, but I can't accept it as correct in less than 2 days). Anyway, I'm very thankful to everyone who helped me.

Comment: You welcome, you can improve this code in order to use the same markup ammount, it has more javascript but maybe only to have more structure. But your code already works, so its a no brainer :P, good luck with your project ;)